# Java: How to convert a string (HH:MM:SS) to a duration?

Tags: java, string, duration

i want to convert a string with a format of HH:MM:SS or MM:SS or SS into a datatype of Duration.

solution:

```
    private ArrayList<Duration> myCdDuration = new ArrayList<Duration>();

        private void convert(String aDuration) {

            chooseNewDuration(stringToInt(splitDuration(aDuration))); //stringToInt() returns an int[] and splitDuration() returns a String[]
        }

        private void chooseNewDuration(int[] array) {
            int elements = array.length;
            switch (elements) {
            case 1:
                myCdDuration.add(newDuration(true, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, array[0]));
                break;
            case 2:
                myCdDuration.add(newDuration(true, 0, 0, 0, 0, array[0], array[1]));
                break;
            case 3:
                myCdDuration.add(newDuration(true, 0, 0, 0, array[0], array[1],
                        array[2]));
                break;
            }
        }
```

thanks for help ...  any easier way to do that ? -> create your own Duration class:

```
public class Duration {
        private int intSongDuration;
        private String printSongDuration;

        public String getPrintSongDuration() {
            return printSongDuration;
        }

        public void setPrintSongDuration(int songDuration) {
            printSongDuration = intToStringDuration(songDuration);
        }

        public int getIntSongDuration() {
            return intSongDuration;
        }

        public void setIntSongDuration(int songDuration) {
            intSongDuration = songDuration;
        }

        public Duration(int songDuration) {

            setIntSongDuration(songDuration);
        }
```

Converts the int value into a String for output/print:

```
private String intToStringDuration(int aDuration) {
    String result = "";

    int hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0;

    hours = aDuration / 3600;
    minutes = (aDuration - hours * 3600) / 60;
    seconds = (aDuration - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60));

    result = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can't just cast a String as any another object as programming doesn't work that way. Perhaps you want to show us what the Duration class looks like. Perhaps it has a constructor that takes a Date object or that takes Strings or ints?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/Duration.html

Comment: Duration class for the use in XML...not to be used other wise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your `myCdDuration` is confusing. Do you want *one* `Duration` object equivalent to whatever was specified in the string, or a list of `Duration` objects where the first contains the hours, the second minutes etc?
2. You can't just cast a `String` into some other object. You should parse the value into an numeric type and use [`DataTypeFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html) to construct the `Duration` object.

Comment: to 1: a list...element 0 for hours etc.. but on a second look it will be easier to create only 1 object because the duration class got methods like getHouts(), getMinutes() and getSeconds()                               to 2: thanks..ill try it

Comment: thanks for 2. ...its workin but looks awful in my program code, converting from string[] to int[] and creating the newDuration with a switch/case statement because of all those different parameters.

Comment: Are you *sure* you need to use the `javax.xml.datatype.Duration` class in the first place? As others have stated, it's designed to be used with the Java XML library. Looking at your other question, if you want to just store the length of a CD track, I'd use a plain old `int` and store the duration in seconds, much like Mansoor's answer (or use the http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ library, if I expect that I'll need to write a lot of code dealing with times, dates and/or durations).

Comment: well...thanks everyone. i created a class Duration with private classvariable int intSongDuration and String printSongDuration. that class also has a method public String intToStringDuration(intaDuration) which converts the int aDuraation into a hh:mm:ss String.

Answer (score 42):

## tl;dr

No need to define your own `Duration` class, as Java provides one.

```
Duration.between (                  // Represent a span of time of hours, minutes, seconds. 
    LocalTime.MIN ,                 // 00:00:00
    LocalTime.parse ( "08:30:00" )  // Parse text as a time-of-day. 
)                                   // Returns a `Duration` object, a span-of-time. 
.toString()                         // Generate a `String` with text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> PT8H30M

And parse standard ISO 8601 formatted text.

```
Duration.parse( "PT8H30M" )   // Parse standard ISO 8601 text yo get a `Duration` object.
```

---

[image: Table of span-of-time classes in Java and in the ThreeTen-Extra project]

---

## Avoid `HH:MM:SS` format

If by the string `08:30:00` you mean "eight and a half hours" span of time rather than a time-of-day “half-past eight in the morning”, then avoid that format of `HH:MM:SS`. That format ambiguous, appearing to be a time-of-day. Instead use the standard ISO 8601 format discussed below.

Duration and time-of-day are two very different concepts. You must be clear on them, each should be distinct in your mind. Using the ambiguous format of HH:MM:SS makes that distinction all the more difficult (so avoid that format!).

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes.

### `LocalTime`

First parse your string as a [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). This class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone. Having no time zone means these objects are based on a generic 24-hour clock without regard for anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

We do not really want a `LocalTime` as your input string represents a span of time rather than a time-of-day. But this is just the first step.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse ( "08:30:00" );
```

### `Duration`

To represent the desired span-of-time, we want the [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class. This class is for spans of time not attached to the timeline. We can create one by converting that `LocalTime` via getting the amount of time from the beginning of the time-of-day clock, `00:00:00.0` or [`LocalTime.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MIN), and the `lt` we just instantiated.

```
Duration d = Duration.between ( LocalTime.MIN , lt );
```

### Editing the input string

The approach above using `LocalTime` only works if your input strings represent a duration of less than 24 hours. If over 24 hours, you will parse the input string yourself.

Something like the following code. Of course the actual parsing depends on resolving the ambiguity of your particular input string. Is `50:00` meant to be fifty hours or fifty minutes? (This ambiguity is a strong reason to avoid this confusing format whenever possible, and stick with ISO 8601 formats.)

```
String input = "50:00";  // Or "50:00:00" (fifty hours, either way)

String[] parts = input.split ( ":" );
Duration d = Duration.ZERO;
if ( parts.length == 3 ) {
    int hours = Integer.parseInt ( parts[ 0 ] );
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt ( parts[ 1 ] );
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt ( parts[ 2 ] );
    d = d.plusHours ( hours ).plusMinutes ( minutes ).plusSeconds ( seconds );
} else if ( parts.length == 2 ) {
    int hours = Integer.parseInt ( parts[ 0 ] );
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt ( parts[ 1 ] );
    d = d.plusHours ( hours ).plusMinutes ( minutes );
} else {
    System.out.println ( "ERROR - Unexpected input." );
}
```

### ISO 8601

We can see the result by generating a String in standard [ISO 8601 format for durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) by simply calling [`Duration::toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toString--). The java.time classes use ISO 8601 by default when parsing/generating strings. For durations, the standard format is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates the years-months-days portion from the hours-minutes-seconds portion. So, our eight-and-a-half hours will appear as `PT8H30M`.

System.out.println ( "d.toString(): " + d );

> d.toString(): PT8H30M

### Collecting `Duration` objects

You can make a `List` holding elements of the type `Duration`.

```
List<Duration> durations = new ArrayList<>( 3 );  // Initial capacity of 3 elements.
durations.add( d ) ;
durations.add( Duration.between ( LocalTime.MIN , LocalTime.parse ( "03:00:00" ) ) ) ;
durations.add( Duration.between ( LocalTime.MIN , LocalTime.parse ( "01:15:00" ) ) ) ;
```

> durations.toString(): [PT8H30M, PT3H, PT1H15M]

Remember that the strings you see in that output like `PT8H30M` are just that: output of generated strings. The `Duration` type is *not* a simple string but rather *generates* a String object by its [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toString--) method.

If you stick to the ISO 8601 formats, you can easily parse as well as generate such strings. No need to go through the `LocalTime` conversion rigamarole we performed at the top of this Answer.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "PT8H30M" );
```

See this example [code live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/g1zkMC).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Those using spring might also want to look at `DurationStyle::detectAndParse` which also allows for a more readable format like `30ms` in addition to ISO-8601. ([Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-conversion), sort of)

Answer (score 20):

I assume what you're ultimately trying to achieve is to compute the duration of the CD in seconds.

There are several ways to do this, but I think the most straightforward is to just split on `:` to get the hours, minutes, and seconds fields, then to compute the duration manually:

```
String timestampStr = "14:35:06";
String[] tokens = timestampStr.split(":");
int hours = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
int seconds = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
int duration = 3600 * hours + 60 * minutes + seconds;
```

Comment: Answering before we even know what Duration is is bound to get you the wrong answer.

Comment: Despite not knowing what Frank is trying to do with `javax.xml.datatype.Duration`, I thought his ultimate goal was pretty clear from the subject.  But I do see your point, I could be wrong. :P  I edited to my answer to state my assumptions.

Comment: So now what? He'll try to cast the int as a Duration? The key was to understand the Duration data type and then with it find the proper way to construct it -- here with a DataTypeFactory as shown by andri (1+ to him).

Comment: As alex pointed out, who knows whether the `Duration` class is even appropriate?  There's no XML in or around Frank's code, so it might be useful to just look at the broader goal that he's trying to achieve.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels He need to parse amount of time from the string (or get inside of your hovercraft to go to the loony bin!! ;)

Comment: @Michael: I'm already there!  But yeah, I agree, and that's why I removed my down-vote on Mansoor's answer. I think the main problem here is that it was a poorly written question.

Answer (score 6):

### java.time.Duration

A couple of other answers have already mentioned that the `Duration` class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is the class to use for a duration. There are some ways to parse your strings into a `java.time.Duration`, and it’s honestly not clear which one is the best. I’d like to present my way.

Do not confuse with `javax.xml.datatype.Duration`, which, as others have said, should only be used with XML documents.

**Basic**

I start simple with just one possible format, hh:mm:ss, for example `01:30:41` for 1 hour 30 minutes 41 seconds.

```
    String durationString = "01:30:41";
    
    String iso = durationString.replaceFirst(
            "^(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})$", "PT$1H$2M$3S");
    Duration dur = Duration.parse(iso);
    
    System.out.format("%-10s  Total %2d minutes or %4d seconds%n",
            dur, dur.toMinutes(), dur.toSeconds());
```

Output so far is:

> ```
> PT1H30M41S  Total 90 minutes or 5441 seconds
> ```

The `Duration.parse` method requires ISO 8601 format. It goes like `PT1H30M41S` for 1 hour 30 minutes 41 seconds. So what I do is I convert your string into this format through a regular expression. The `$1`, etc., in my replacement string will be substituted by what was matched by the *groups* in round brackets in the regular expression. So `durationString.replaceFirst()` converts your string to `PT01H30M41S`, which `Duration` can parse.

**Three formats**

You asked for conversion of *HH:MM:SS or MM:SS or SS*. The modification to the above is actually quite simple: we just need three calls to `replaceFirst()` instead of one. Exactly one of them will succeed in replacing anything. The other two will just return the string unchanged.

```
    String[] durationStrings = { "01:32:43", "26:31", "14" };
    
    for (String durationString : durationStrings) {
        String iso = durationString.replaceFirst("^(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})$", "PT$1H$2M$3S")
                .replaceFirst("^(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})$", "PT$1M$2S")
                .replaceFirst("^(\\d{2})$", "PT$1S");
        Duration dur = Duration.parse(iso);
        
        System.out.format("%-10s  Total %2d minutes or %4d seconds%n",
                dur, dur.toMinutes(), dur.toSeconds());
    }
```

> ```
> PT1H32M43S  Total 92 minutes or 5563 seconds
> PT26M31S    Total 26 minutes or 1591 seconds
> PT14S       Total  0 minutes or   14 seconds
> ```

### Time4J and net.time4j.Duration

In case you’re fine with an external dependency, the Time4J library offers a much more elegant way of parsing your strings to duration objects. We first declare a formatter:

```
private static final Duration.Formatter<ClockUnit> FORMATTER 
        = Duration.formatter(ClockUnit.class, "[[hh:]mm:]ss");
```

The square brackets in the format pattern string surround optional parts, so this formatter accepts all of hh:mm:ss, mm:ss and just ss.

```
    for (String durationString : durationStrings) {
        Duration<ClockUnit> dur = FORMATTER.parse(durationString);

        long minutes = dur.with(ClockUnit.MINUTES.only())
                .getPartialAmount(ClockUnit.MINUTES);
        long seconds = dur.with(ClockUnit.SECONDS.only())
                .getPartialAmount(ClockUnit.SECONDS);
        
        System.out.format("%-10s  Total %2d minutes or %4d seconds%n",
                dur, minutes, seconds);
    }
```

Output is the same as before:

> ```
> PT1H32M43S  Total 92 minutes or 5563 seconds
> PT26M31S    Total 26 minutes or 1591 seconds
> PT14S       Total  0 minutes or   14 seconds
> ```

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Time4J - API, Tutorials and Examples](http://time4j.net/)

Comment: In the last few days, I have seen you posting Time4J solution along with `java.time` solution. This is indeed a great step forward because Time4J is also popular especially among Android developers.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest *not* using `javax.xml.datatype.Duration`, as its related to the XML Java API and it's confusing to use it if you are not dealing with XML. Moreover, it is an abstract class, and there's no non-abstract documented implementation of it in Java SE, so you'd have to either create your own non-abstract implementation or obtain an instance somehow (probably, playing with the XML API).

You manage time and dates in Java using the `Date` and `Calendar` classes. To convert `String`s to `Date`/`Calendar` you use `DateFormat` or `SimpleDateFormat`. That will let you perform your duration arithmetic, although that's not 100% pretty.

Mansoor provides a way to do stuff manually using String manipulation and handling durations as numeric values- if you only do simple stuff, it might be more straightforward to do that.

If you have to perform more complex stuff, you might want to look into http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If it is homework, then Frank may have no choice of not using Duration.

Comment: @Frank No no!! Duration for XML using ONLY

Answer (score 2):

I have written this method in my utils class to parse various kind of duration strings. It is quite flexible :

```
public static int getSecondsFromFormattedDuration(String duration){
        if(duration==null)
            return 0;
        try{

            Pattern patternDuration = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?::\\d+){0,2}");

            int hours = 0;
            int minutes = 0;
            int seconds = 0;
            if(patternDuration.matcher(duration).matches()){
                String[] tokens = duration.split(":");
                if(tokens.length==1){
                    seconds = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
                }else if(tokens.length == 2){
                    minutes = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
                    seconds = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                }else{
                    hours = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
                    minutes = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                    seconds = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                }

                return 3600 * hours + 60 * minutes + seconds;
            }else
                return 0;

        }catch (NumberFormatException ignored){
            return 0;
        }

}
```

This is how it parsed these durations :

```
"1"   -->  1
"10"  -->  10
"10:"   -->  0  (not a valid duration)
"10:07"   -->  607
"06:08"   -->  368
"7:22"   -->  442
":22"   -->  0  (not a valid duration)
"10:32:33"   -->  37953
"2:33:22"   -->  9202
"2:2:02"   -->  7322
"2:33:43:32"   -->  0  (not a valid duration)
"33ff"   -->  0  (not a valid duration)
"2d:33"   -->  0  (not a valid duration)
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 and Java.time.Duration you can do this given that the string is of the format HH:MM:SS or MM:SS or SS

```
Duration.ofSeconds(Arrays.stream(runtime.split(":"))
                  .mapToInt(n -> Integer.parseInt(n))
                  .reduce(0, (n, m) -> n * 60 + m));
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but what about values like "777:888:999999"? They would work with this proposal, but do they actually conform to the format "HH:MM:SS"?

Comment: No reason why it shouldn't work, given that the data of 777 hours, 888 minutes and 999999 seconds makes sense. Multiples the previous value with 60 and adds the current values. So you'd end up with the result of (((0 * 60 + 777) * 60 + 888) * 60 + 999999) and makes that into a duration based on the result.
If there is a requirement on that the length per field is only 2, you'd could potentially add a peek or map that handles the checkl.

Answer (score 0):

Sample, Convert Current DateTime to Duration in Java 7.

```
DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())
```

Output -

P48Y5M13DT19H59M24.658S