# Converting duration string into milliseconds in Java

Tags: java, duration, milliseconds

I apologize if this has already been discussed.

I have a clip duration in a string:

```
00:10:17
```

I would like to convert that to value in milliseconds. (Basically 617000 for the above string)

Is there some API that I could use to do this in one or two steps. 
On basic way would be to split the string and then add the minutes, seconds and hours.

But is there a shorter way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: no date, just duration in HH:MM:SS

Comment: Similar Question: [Java: How to convert a string (HH:MM:SS) to a duration?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8257641/642706)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one own written possible approach(assumption of same source format always)

```
String source = "00:10:17";
String[] tokens = source.split(":");
int secondsToMs = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) * 1000;
int minutesToMs = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) * 60000;
int hoursToMs = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) * 3600000;
long total = secondsToMs + minutesToMs + hoursToMs;
```

Comment: @Sunny thanks for accepting(but assylias's answer has cleaner solution so use assylias's solution.

Answer (score 12):

## `java.time.Duration`

Use the [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
Duration.between( 
    LocalTime.MIN , 
    LocalTime.parse( "00:10:17" ) 
).toMillis()
```

> milliseconds: 617000

See this [code live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/UxM90y).

See [this Answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41453329/642706) and [this Answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41452921/642706) to similar Questions for more explanation of `Duration`, `LocalTime`, and a java.time.

**Caution:** Beware of possible data-loss when converting from possible values of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) in java.time objects to your desired [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).

Answer (score 9):

You could simply parse it manually:

```
String s = "00:10:17";
String[] data = s.split(":");

int hours  = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
int seconds = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);

int time = seconds + 60 * minutes + 3600 * hours;
System.out.println("time in millis = " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(time, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

Comment: +1 assylias for `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(time, TimeUnit.SECONDS));` Wow :] i really didn't know about that. Nice touch

Comment: @Sajmon I could have used it for the calculation of time too but was a bit lazy - it is admittedly quite verbose ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDuration = "00:10:17";
        int[] parts = Arrays.stream(strDuration.split(":"))
                            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                            .toArray();

        Duration duration = Duration.ZERO;
        long millis = 0;

        if (parts.length == 3) {
            millis = duration.plusHours(parts[0])
                                .plusMinutes(parts[1])
                                .plusSeconds(parts[2])
                                .toMillis();
        }

        System.out.println(millis);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
617000
```

**Note:** I've used `Stream` API to convert the `String[]` to `int[]`. You can do it without using `Stream` API as follows:

```
String strDuration = "00:10:17";
String[] strParts = strDuration.split(":");
int[] parts = new int[strParts.length];
for (int i = 0; i < strParts.length; i++) {
    parts[i] = Integer.parseInt(strParts[i]);
}
```

*Alternatively*, you can parse the parts at the time of adding them to `Duration` as follows:

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDuration = "00:10:17";
        String[] parts = strDuration.split(":");

        Duration duration = Duration.ZERO;
        long millis = 0;

        if (parts.length == 3) {
            millis = duration.plusHours(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]))
                                .plusMinutes(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]))
                                .plusSeconds(Integer.parseInt(parts[2]))
                                .toMillis();
        }

        System.out.println(millis);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
617000
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

1. For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
2. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Some great tutorials on Java `Stream` API:**

1. [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams, Part 1](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html)
2. [Part 2: Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html)
3. [Lesson: Aggregate Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)
4. [Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) [Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_duration.html) class.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 0):

Create an appropriate instance of `DateFormat`. Use the `parse()` method to get a `Date`. Use `getTime()` on the `Date` object to get milliseconds.

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826270/how-to-convert-hhmmss-sss-to-milliseconds) .

I just tested it as:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Test {        
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        String inputString = "00:10:17";

        Date date = sdf .parse(inputString);// .parse("1970-01-01" + inputString);
        System.out.println("in milliseconds: " + date.getTime());        
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it won't work as it would give the time in milliseconds till that particular time

Comment: The "trick" that makes it work in the link is to set the day to 1st January 1970. If you don't you will get an incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if the duration includes hours or minutes or seconds or none.

```
  public static long durationToMillis(String duration) {
    String[] parts = duration.split(":");
    long result = 0;
    for (int i = parts.length - 1, j = 1000; i >= 0; i--, j *= 60) {
        try {
            result += Integer.parseInt(parts[i]) * j;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A duplicate question (link at the bottom) asked about a string without seconds, just `HH:MM`, for example `25:25`, using Java 7. I still recommend the `Duration` class of java.time, the modern Java date and time API. java.time has been backported to Java 6 and 7. With it there are a number of ways to go. It’s simple to adapt one of the good answers by Basil Bourque and Live and Let Live to a string without seconds. I am showing yet an approach.

```
    String durationString = "25:25"; // HH:MM, so 25 hours 25 minutes
    String isoDurationString
            = durationString.replaceFirst("^(\\d+):(\\d{2})$", "PT$1H$2M");
    long durationMilliseconds = Duration.parse(isoDurationString).toMillis();
    System.out.format(Locale.US, "%,d milliseconds%n", durationMilliseconds);
```

Output when running on Java 1.7.0_67:

> 91,500,000 milliseconds

`Duration.parse()` accepts only ISO 8601 format, for example `PT25T25M`. Think a period of time of 25 hours 25 minutes. So I am using a regular expression for converting the string you had into the required format.

One limitation of this approach (a limitation shared with some of the other approaches) is that it gives poor validation. We would like reject minutes greater than 59, but `Duration.parse()` accepts them.

### Question: Did you claim that it works on Java 1.7?

Yes indeed, java.time just requires at least **Java 1.6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Duplicate question: Java convert time string to milliseconds [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65792937/java-convert-time-string-to-milliseconds)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Other answers using java.time

  - [Answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41453448/5772882) converting via `LocalTime`, a hack that works up to 23 hours 59 minutes and does validate that minutes don’t exceed 59.
  - [Answer by Live and Let Live](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65794686/5772882) parsing each integer and assembling into a `Duration`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)