# How to parse different time formats

Tags: java, datetime, time, localtime

I have different time formats in string (from videoplayer counter).
For example:

```
03:45 -> 3 munutes, 45 seconds
1:03:45 -> 1 hour, 3 munutes, 45 seconds
123:03:45 -> 123 hours, 3 munutes, 45 seconds
```

How can I parse all this formats with LocalTime lib?

If I using such code:

```
LocalTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[H[H]:]mm:ss"));
```

It works fine for "1:03:45" or "11:03:45", but for "03:55" I have exception

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '03:55' could not be parsed at index 5
```

Comment: Probably just a side note: you're using the wrong data type for your value. `Duration` is a more appropriate type for these values. For example, you can't store `123:03:45` in a `localTime` object (`123` is out of range for hours)

Comment: 123:03:45 is a duration not a local time. You could directly split on :'s and extract the hour, min, sec components.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Timestamp string “HH:mm:ss” to Duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292575/converting-timestamp-string-hhmmss-to-duration)

Comment: Hi @OleV.V. I don't think the OP ask for `HH:mm:ss` but any format of `mm:ss` and `HH:mm:ss`, I don't see any answer can answer this specific question

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more possibilities. I would probably go for modifying the time string to conform with the syntax accepted by `Duration.parse`.

```
    String[] timeStrings = { "03:45", "1:03:45", "123:03:45" };
    for (String timeString : timeStrings) {
        String modifiedString = timeString.replaceFirst("^(\\d+):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})$", "PT$1H$2M$3S")
                .replaceFirst("^(\\d+):(\\d{2})$", "PT$1M$2S");
        System.out.println("Duration: " + Duration.parse(modifiedString));
    }
```

Output is:

> ```
> Duration: PT3M45S
> Duration: PT1H3M45S
> Duration: PT123H3M45S
> ```

The case of hours, minutes and seconds (two colons) is handled by the first call to `replaceFirst`, which in turn removes both colons and makes sure that the second `replaceFirst` doesn’t replace anything. In the case of just one colon (minutes and seconds), the first `replaceFirst` cannot replcae anything and passes the string unchanged to the second `replaceFirst` call, which in turn transforms to the ISO 8601 format accepted by `Duration.parse`.

You need the `Duration` class for two reasons: (1) If I understand correctly, your time string denotes a duration, so using `LocalTime` is incorrect and will confuse those maintaining your code after you. (2) The maximum value of a `LocalTime` is 23:59:59.999999999, so it will never accept 123:03:45.

Comment: Intelligent solution Ole V.V. ;)

Answer (score 0):

From comments and what I read before, you can't parse `mm:ss`, to solve your issue lets convert all the times to seconds and then convert that seconds to a **Duration** and not to **LocalTime**, here is a solution for your problem :

```
String[] times = {"03:45", "1:03:45", "123:03:45"};
for (String time : times) {
    List<Integer> parts = Arrays.stream(time.split(":"))
            .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.reverse(parts);

    int seconds = (int) IntStream.range(0, parts.size())
            .mapToDouble(index -> parts.get(index) * Math.pow(60, index))
            .sum();

    Duration result = Duration.ofSeconds(seconds);
    System.out.println(result);    
}
```

**Outputs or duration is**

```
PT3M45S              -> 03:45 
PT1H3M45S            -> 1:03:45  
PT123H3M45S          -> 123:03:45
```