# Duration.ofMinutes(0) - how to pass user entered value from GUI to set value instead of zero

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I would like to have you help of `private Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes(0);`  it is set for 0 minute. I have this line of code in as a class variable. It supposed to be a counter. It counts back from the time set. What i have done is, I have created a GUI and created a texfield where user can enter an integer and that integer should be passed to the `Duration.ofMintues()`. I have tried many different ways without succeed, now i would like to ask your help to countinue on with it.

reference: csibman
[Java: How to convert a string (HH:MM:SS) to a duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257641/java-how-to-convert-a-string-hhmmss-to-a-duration)

Comment: Can you show your code? Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)