# Time Format in Excel/CSV

Tags: java, csv, datetime, time

I have a CSV with time value as one column & it has below list of values

[image]

Excel has formatted this time value to normal time format. i.e.

> 44:11.0 --> 12:44:11 AM

Even if i open this CSV in text editor value is displayed as 44:11.0.

Please help me understand this time format, as i need to implement parser for this column CSV in Java.

Comment: What does 44 & 11.0 signify? are they minutes and seconds?

Comment: Refer (https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/06/23/excel-time-format-now-time-functions/) . The decimal portion is the time, in your case, while the data is being generated (and converted), the integer portion (the date) is somehow being lost and the resulting time is being formatted as Excel time only. You could check how the data is being generated and the Excel export procedure from the source.

Comment: Are the times durations, amounts of time, 44 minutes 11.0 seconds? And why the java tag?

Comment: @OleV.V. I had added Java tag.. because i need to parse & format this time string using Java SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @DusayantaPrasad: i am trying to understand this excel formatted time. It formats 44:11.0 to 12:44:11. I dont know whether it is correct way of formatting.

Comment: I recommend that you stay away from `SimpleDateFormat`. It’s a notorious troublemaker of a class. And while it can parse and format a time of day such as 12:44:11 AM (depending), it cannot parse a duration such as 44 minutes 11.0 seconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: How to convert a string (HH:MM:SS) to a duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257641/java-how-to-convert-a-string-hhmmss-to-a-duration) There are more similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Apache Commons CSV` to read `.csv` files.

Download the jar from here - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi

You can try this :

I created an .csv file in my local - Book1.csv

[image]

You should modify the column to make your work easier.

Select the all the rows of the column and right click and click on Format cells.

[image]

Click on number tab -> Click on Custom menu and select -> hh:mm:ss

[image]

After this Click on OK to get the changes.

[image]

The code :

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        try (Reader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Anish\\Desktop\\Book1.csv");
                CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);) {
            System.out.println("Loaded");
            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser.getRecords()) {
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                Date date = format.parse(csvRecord.get(0));
                System.out.println(date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Loaded
0:44:11
0:29:4
0:22:41
```

Comment: Yes, I am able to find the format using your suggestion. I identified the format & used that same format in Java to decode the value. Thank you